# How can I create a list of all files in subdirectories while remaining the right order?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am trying to get a list of all the files in several subdirectories. However, it shuffles the order when I do so with this code:

```
os.chdir = "current working directory"

filelist = listdir(".")

newlist = []

for file in filelist:
    x = listdir(file)
    for file2 in file:
        path = join(getcwd(), file, file2)
        newlist.append(path)

sorted(newlist)
```

When I execute this code, I get the following output:

[image]

However, I would like to remain the order had in the files, like:

[image]

When I try to sort it by integer I get the following error:

> *ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)  in ()
>   ----> 1 sorted(newlist, key=int) ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: '/Users/michielaarts/Desktop/NEW DATASET TEST
>   VERSION/13_01_2016_13_30_02_4191/1'*

Anyone can help? Many thanks!

Comment: content shown in both images are different hence please write actual order which you want as output.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean. I would like to keep the order from the second picture, so 0jpg - 1jpg - 2jpg etc. Then the next directory should be accessed which also contains images called 0jpg - 1jpg - 2jpg etc.

Comment: I think for the ValueError is because the `key` parameter to `sorted()` expects the `int` portion to be identified explicitly, give it the last character of the path, something like `sorted(newlist, key=lambda last_char: int(last_char[-1]))`, should point to the last character (the "`1`" in the path from the path in the error example). referenced from: https://docs.python.org/3.4/howto/sorting.html#sortinghowto